# rewriting one expression as other expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone explain as how we can rewrite the first expression as second ? I am not able to pick the step done to change from 1 to 2.

$f(N) = 2^{(N+1)/2 + 1 }- 2$, for odd $N$

becomes

$f(N) = 2^{(N+1)/2} + 2^{(N+1)/2}- 2$, for odd $N$

Comment: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may help.

Comment: $2^{x+1} = 2^x \cdot 2^1 = 2 \cdot 2^x$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow as new to math jax ,i am finding it really difficult to edit the required part

Answer (score 2):

$$
f(N)=2^{(N+1)/2+1}-2=2\cdot2^{(N+1)/2}-2=2^{(N+1)/2}+2^{(N+1)/2}-2.
$$

Comment: how do you write 2 as 2^(N+1)/2 IN THIRD STEP .can you just throw light on  what i am missing ?

Comment: For any $x$, $2x=x+x$, since you have two of them. In this case, we have two of $2^{(N+1)/2}$.

Comment: aah my bad thankyou